# How to add values from different table that has the same id number?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, multiple-tables

I have 7 tables, each table has a column for total I need to get the total of each table which has the same id number, these are 3 sample tables:

clean table

> clean_id | labor_expense | machine_expense | diesel_expense | clean_total 
>  
>         1       |         1000         |        2000              |         500       |           3500 
>       2       |         2000         |        1000              |         1000     |          4500

plant_table

> plant_id | labor_expense | machine_expense | plant_expense | plant_total 
>  
>         
>   1       |         
>   1000         |        
>   2000              |         
>   500       |           3500 
>        2       |         2000         |        1000              |         1000     |          4500

fertilize_table

> fertilize_id | labor_expense | machine_expense | fertilizer_expense | fertilize_total 
>  
>         
>   1       |         
>   1000         |        
>   2000              |         
>   500       |           3500 
>        2       |         2000         |        1000              |         1000     |          4500

How can I get the total of clean_total, plant_total and fertilize_total that have the same id number?

I was thinking to save it to another table like total_expense but I only get the total of the first id number

total_expenses

> total_id | clean_total | plant_total | fertilize_total | total_expenses 
>  
>         
>   1       |         
>   3500         |        
>   3500              |         
>   3500       |           10500 
>        2       |         4500         |        4500              |         4500     |          13500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rows for each ID are known to exist in all tables, you can simply join them:

```
SELECT clean_id AS total_id,
       clean_total + plant_total + fertilize_total AS total_expenses
FROM clean_table
JOIN plant_table ON clean_id = plant_id
JOIN fertilize_table ON clean_id = fertilize_id
```